# NoMethodError: undefined method `stub!' for nil:NilClass

Tags: activerecord, rspec, specifications

I'm trying to put the rspec for active link condition present in the application_helper.rb.
Application_helper.rb code:

```
def active_class(link_path)
    current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
  end
```

i tried to put the rspec for this active_class method, i used stub for this purpose.This is my rspec code for active_class method.
Application_helper_spec.rb code:

```
describe 'when called from "index" action' do
  before
    helper.stub!(:action_name).and_return('index')
  end
  it 'should do' do
    helper.active_class.should == 'active'
  end


describe 'when called from "other" action' do
  before
    helper.stub!(:action_name).and_return('other')
  end
  it 'should do' do
    helper.active_class.should == 'empty'
  end
```

I'm getting the error as undefined method stub.How can i get overcome from this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use slightly different interface for stubbing and mocking which looks like this:

```
allow(helper).to receive(:action_name).and_return('index')
```

When you just want to stub the response.

But if you need to set up an expectation:

```
expect(helper).to receive(:action_name).and_return('index')
```

You can find more info in the docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/basics

Comment: Thanks for your response,when i add this code in my condition, i got the error as undefined method 'to'. Is there any better way to change this?

Comment: That's weird because it's part of standard rspec. Can you try the same with valilla rails + rspec app? Maybe some of your gems, or other config is interfering with rspec mock/stub lib?